# how to get a jqgrid object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am trying to assign a JQGrid object to a var so that I can call .setGridWidth on it like so:

```
var subGridName = 'allDetailsJqGrid_' + idList[i];
var grid = $(subGridName);
grid.setGridWidth(width);
```

but subGrid seems to be coming back as a plain Javascript object instead of an actual JQGrid.  How can I get the actual JQGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding '_t' to the end of my id.  '_t' must be something JQGrid adds to the actual JQGrid name.

```
var subGridName = 'allDetailsJqGrid_' + idList[i] + '_t';
var grid = $('#' + subGridName);
grid.setGridWidth(width);
```

I sure hope this helps someone because it took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the jqGrid as a jQuery object at all.. but as a sting instead..

Missing **$** or **jQuery** to convert it to a jQuery Object

Try

```
var subGrid = $('myJqGrid_' + 999);
```